# Update two rows based on two different constraints

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpql

I have a table `X` which has a column `BALANCE`. I have two row ids and a value `amount`. There are two constraint variables - `MAX_BALANCE` and `MIN_BALANCE`.

I need to write an update query which updates the column `BALANCE`. The first row id's `BALANCE` is added with `amount` and the `amount` is subtracted from the second row id's `BALANCE`. I need to ensure that the `BALANCE` always stays within the range. That is, `MIN_BALANCE` <= `BALANCE` <= `MAX_BALANCE`.

I am not supposed to update one row and then roll back if the number of rows updated is not equal to 2. The update query should either update two rows (success case) or it should not update any row at all.

I am using Hibernate in Java and here is the query which I have tried. It doesn't work for the success case.

```
String sql = "UPDATE X x "
                + "SET x.balance = CASE "
                + "WHEN x.id = :rowId1 THEN (x.balance + :amount) "
                + "WHEN x.id = :rowId2 THEN (x.balance - :amount) "
                + "END "
                + "WHERE x.id IN :ids "
                + "AND ((x.id = :rowId1 AND x.balance + :amount <= :MAX_BALANCE) "
                + "OR (x.id = :rowId2 AND x.balance - :amount >= :MIN_BALANCE))";
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery(sql);

        List<BigInteger> ids = Arrays.asList(new BigInteger(rowId1), new BigInteger(rowId2));


        int rows = query.setParameter("amount", amount)
            .setParameter("ids", ids)
            .setParameter("rowId1", new BigInteger(rowId1))
            .setParameter("rowId2", new BigInteger(rowId2))
            .setParameter("MAX_BALANCE", new Float(MAX_BALANCE))
            .setParameter("MIN_BALANCE", new Float(MIN_BALANCE))
            .executeUpdate();
```

I don't want to check if `rows == 1` and throw an exception. The update query should always ensure that rows will take the value either 0 or 2.

Or is there a way to perform this operation based on Criteria Update in Hibernate?

Answer (score 1):

You need to self join your table on itself. The first instance should have the record for rowid1 and the 2nd instance should have the record for rowid2. This way you can check the balances of both records in one go and make the decision whether to update or not.

```
update x x1 join x x2
set x1.balance=if(x1.balance+:amount <= :MAX_BALANCE,x1.balance+:amount, x1.balance),
    x2.balance=if(x2.balance-:amount >= :MIN_BALANCE,x2.balance-:amount, x2.balance)    
where x1.id=:rowid1 and x2.id=rowid2
```

Comment: This almost works. I modified the query like this, 

`update x x1 join x x2
set x1.balance=x1.balance+:amount,
    x2.balance=x2.balance-:amount   
where x1.id=:rowid1 and x2.id=rowid2 and x1.balance+:amount <= :MAX_BALANCE and x2.balance-:amount >= :MIN_BALANCE` and now it works.

Comment: But the problem is, the query doesn't work with Hibernate JPQL.

I get the following error.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting "set", found 'JOIN' because JPA 2 doesn't support this. I don't want to use nativeQuery.

Comment: Then try to use a comma instead of the word join.

Comment: No. Still the same exception. expecting "set", found ','

Comment: Then use a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

try this ...

```
String sql = "UPDATE X x "
+ "SET x.balance = CASE "
+ "WHEN x.id = :rowId1 AND x.balance + :amount <= :MAX_BALANCE THEN (x.balance + :amount) "
+ "WHEN x.id = :rowId2 AND x.balance - :amount >= :MIN_BALANCE THEN (x.balance - :amount) "
+ "END "
+ "WHERE x.id = :rowId1 OR x.id = :rowId2";
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work. When one balance goes to the negative, it gets the value `null`.

Comment: if rowId2 has not sufficient balance then what you need to do?

Comment: i think this is not possible with one statement. it needs more than one statement.

Comment: you can use stored procedure for it.